# Nunit-console.exe fails with return code 7 using Nant and Bamboo

Tags: nunit, nant, bamboo, nunit-console

I'm getting not too much saing error while running nunit test on Bamboo build server. 
It causes showing build resuts as red and shows that project has only 27 unit test and all they passing (project has more than 500 tests and some are failing)
I've tried to run the same test using nunit-console on my local machine, but it runs without any problems.
Bamboo log:

```
[exec] D:\BambooAgent\..\nant.build(277,5): 
[exec] External Program Failed: C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.9\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe (return code was 7)
```

Do you have any ideas how can I debug this problem or what `return code 7` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [NUnit discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/1BXhewdOgho), the return code from `nunit-console` is either:

- zero if all tests passed
- negative if `nunit-console` could not run for some reason
- or a positive number indicating how many tests failed.

So a return code of 7 means that 7 of your individual tests failed in some way.